# How to strip large amount of string from TCP

Tags: python, parsing, text, tcplistener, pbx

I am Listening SMDR call history log from PBX via TCP listening. It working fine continouse running. But reconnecting Windows server after certain period of time PBX giving large amount of data, unable to parser the lines.

```
parser = re.compile(';')
        fieldlist = (
            ( "start_date", 'date', '%d.%m.%y' ),
            ( "start_time", 'time',  '%H:%M:%S' ),
            ( "trunk_number", 'str', 2 ),
            ( "internal_station", 'str', 4 ), 
            ( "ring_duration", 'str',5 ),
            ( "call_duration", 'time',  '%H:%M:%S' ),
            ( "external_station", 'str', 15 ),
            ( "call_charge", 'str', 255 ),
            ( "call_info", 'str', 4 ), 
            ( "ac_ct", 'str', 255 ),
            ( "msn_charge", 'str', 255 ),
            ( "sip_station", 'str', 6 ),
            ( "lcr_route", 'str', 10 ),
            ( "inout_station", 'str', 15 ),
            ( "remarks", 'str', 255 ),

        );

        peerinfo = self.request.getpeername()
        log.info(u'Got connection from ' + str(peerinfo[0]) + ' (' + str(peerinfo[1]) + ')')


        #Receive data loop
        global server_running
        dbuffer = ""
        while server_running:
            data = self.request.recv(1024)
            ddata = data.decode('utf-8')
            time.sleep(1)
            #print (data)
            #print (ddata)
            if not data:
                break

            # Append data to LOGFILE
            lgf = open(LOGFILE, 'ab')
            lgf.write(data)
            lgf.close()

            s_data = ddata.split(';')


            # Process data
            line = ddata.strip("\r\n")
            vals = parser.split(line)
            print (vals)
            #print ("internal Station", s_data[3])
            #print ("enternal number", s_data[6])
            #print ("call info", s_data[8])
            #print ("\n")


            if len(vals) >= len(fieldlist):
                dictv = {}
                i = 0
                try:
                    for v in fieldlist:
                        if v[1] == 'date':
                            dictv[v[0]] = datetime.strptime(vals[i], v[2]).date()
                        elif v[1] == 'time':
                            dictv[v[0]] = datetime.strptime(vals[i], v[2]).time()
                        elif v[1] == 'int':
                            dictv[v[0]] = int(vals[i])
                        elif v[1] == 'str':
                            if len(vals[i]) > v[2]:
                                raise ParserError(v[0] + ': String too long')
                            dictv[v[0]] = str(vals[i])
                        else:
                            raise ParserError(v[0] + ': Unknown field type ' + v[1])
                        i += 1 

                except Exception as e:
                    print ("Unable to parse line")
                    log.error(u"Parse error on line (" + str(v[0]) + str(vals[i]) + "): got exception " + str(e) + " (" + str(line) + ")")

                else:
                    print ("Line parsed correctly")
                    log.debug(u"Correctly parsed 1 line: " + str(dictv))

                    #Prepare dictv for query
                    map(lambda v: MySQLdb.string_literal(v), dictv)
                    dictv['table'] = MYSQL_DB['table']
```

Receiving data format as shown below
connection successful
b'\r\n05.09.19;16:18:53;1;6200;;00:14:32;04222309088;;2;;;0;2;;\r\n05.09.19;16:20:05;69;6258;;00:02:13;;;2;;;7510;1;;\r\n05.09.19;16:21:23;2;6210;00:00;00:00:00;261074;;2;;;0;2;;\r\n05.09.19;16:21:50;70;6258;00:03;00:00:51;7524;;1;;;;;6258;\r\n05.09.19;16:22:15;2;6335;00:21;00:00:00;7639177929;;2;;;0;2;;\r\n05.09.19;16:22:16;69;6320;00:01;00:01:50;7211;;1;;;;;6320;\r\n05.09.19;16:23:31;1;6333;00:03;00:02:19;07708841435;;5;;;;;;\r\n05.09.19;16:23:31;71;6333;;00:02:19;;;9;;;7820;1;;\r\n'
['05.09.19', '16:18:53', '1', '6200', '', '00:14:32', '04222309088', '', '2', '', '', '0', '2', '']
Line parsed correctly
b'05.09.19;16:24:34;69;6500;;00:00:07;;;9;;;7815;1;;\r\n05.09.19;16:26:58;1;6335;;00:00:26;7639177929;;2;;;0;2;;\r\n05.09.19;16:27:15;69;6221;00:05;00:00:23;7505;;1;;;;;6217;\r\n05.09.19;16:28:04;70;6335;;00:01:01;;;2;;;7519;1;;\r\n05.09.19;16:28:34;69;6270;;00:00:58;;;2;;;7505;1;;\r\n05.09.19;16:29:04;69;6500;00:03;00:00:00;;;2;;;7815;1;;\r\n05.09.19;16:29:38;69;6500;;00:00:27;;;9;;;7815;1;;\r\n05.09.19;16:29:58;69;6254;00:02;00:00:12;7820;;1;;;;;6254;\r\n05.09.19;16:29:58;70;6333;;00:00:15;;;9;;;7820;1;;\r\n05.09.19;16:29:58;1;6333;00:10;00:00:15;08042994299;;5;;;;;;\r\n05.09.19;16:33:42;69;6259;00:01;00:00:01;7211;;1;;;;;6259;\r\n'
['5.09.19', '16:24:34', '69', '6500', '', '00:00:07', '', '', '9', '', '', '7815', '1', '']
Line parsed correctly

b'05.09.19;16:34:27;69;6262;00:02;00:00:12;7214;;1;;;;;6262;\r\n'
['5.09.19', '16:34:27', '69', '6262', '00:02', '00:00:12', '7214', '', '1', '', '', '', '', '6262']
Line parsed correctly

Comment: you are omitting the actual exception that is logged

Comment: i did not get you. kindly explain brief

Comment: I mean, paste the output that is logged when you get the error, to see which exception is being raised

Comment: now i paste the output. kindly check it